# Infinite Scrolling without scrollbar on ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a ng-grid that has scrollbars (default).
The ng-grid triggers the `ngGridEventScroll` event ([api](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Grid-Events)) when you are at the bottom of the grid.

So far so good but I want this behaviour when there are no scrollbars. The only way I could turn these scrollbars off is by using the [ng-grid-flexible-height.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/plugins/ng-grid-flexible-height.js) plugin but then the `ngGridEventScroll` event is ignored.

I there a way to get this event when you're at the bottom of the grid?
Are there other ways to throw your own custom event?
When using a custom event, the ideal situation would be to throw the event when you're at the last 'x' records (to preload data).

There is a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/empie/n39BW/) (with flexible height plugin enabled, to disable comment out: `,plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()]`)

Thanks for any input!

Comment: So you want an event when there is no scroll bar and the user scrolls over the last row. Is that right ?

Comment: yes, if I have an event then I can watch the event and append extra items to the grid. If there is no such event, I want to find out another way to implement this functionality...

Answer (score 0):

I checked the documentation and I dont think Ng Grid provides incremental loading. You ll need to write custom code for it.

You could use some jquery like as discussed here - [Auto Load More Data On Page Scroll (jQuery/PHP)](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll)

```
$(window).scroll(function() { //detect page scroll    
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) //user scrolled to bottom of the page?
  { // do your stuff here; }
});
```

Or better use a jquery plugin like this one - [jQuery Waypoints](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll/comment-page-1) | [Example](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/)